# Infinispan keyset() not suitable for production

Tags: infinispan

I decided to use infinispan distributed grid to extend my application to support cluster but I encountered a limitation when using this kind of shared resource.
How can I retrieve all the values or keys in the Distributed cache? I'm asking this because in their documentation all the collection methods are not recommended for running in production (meaning keySet()).
Right now I have a local bucket/cache with the pairs key/value but in order to process the values I need to retrieve the keys and iterate throught the set.
Set set = cache.keySet();

When having a large number of entries in the local cache, the keySet() returns a copy and this is a heavy load for the memory.
I tried to use the query feature but there are some network calls if I want to find the values and I don't need that. Also the query feature does not support complex filters.
Do you know which is the best approach when using infinispan in production?

As this is an experimental phase I'm using the last infinispan version.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map/Reduce functionality allows you to iterate over all the entries stored and also migrates the logic where the data is, so doesn't add a lot of burden.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to adapt Map/Reduce model to my application.

Answer (score 0):

We are using keySet() on production for informational purpose only. Performance do not seem to be a big issue under low data loads but of course you should use such methods with great care because they could have large performance impact depending by how you are using the cache. Remote cache queries seems a pretty handy feature to me.